# Why'd a company issue unpaid shares, to acquire or merge companies?

Tags: profits

Under the heading [Why would a company issue unpaid shares?](https://www.informdirect.co.uk/shares/what-are-unpaid-shares/) by Johnathan Korchak

> Although unpaid and partly paid shares are far less common than fully paid shares, there are a number of reasons why a company might choose to issue them:
>
> [...]
>
> [second-last bullet] In line with a strategy to implement an acquisition or merger of companies.

Under the heading [Why would I issue unpaid shares?](https://www.1stformations.co.uk/blog/a-guide-to-company-shares/)

> Companies may choose to issue partly-paid or unpaid shares for a variety of reasons, including:
>
> [...]
>
> [last bullet] As part of a strategy to implement a merger or acquisition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why would a company issue unpaid shares?

Possible reasons are:

- buyer's temporary lack of sufficient funds to perform the
  acquisition, whence the issuer of shares is willing to grant credit for
  the sake of "closing the sale";
- fiscal planning (be it the buyer's and/or the issuer's planning) might be such
  that delaying payment of shares will place him at a more convenient tax bracket
  in the acquisition and/or disbursement fiscal year(s) (this is more evident in [cash based accounting systems](https://www.moneyinstructor.com/doc/cashbased.asp)), and/or the delay of payment will allow
  him to qualify for certain tax deductions;
- issuer predicts the price of shares will fall (and possibly discourage prospects of merger/acquisition), so he hedges against
  that risk by entering a [forward contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_contract) with the buyer, with the incentive --to the buyer-- that transfer of shares will be effective immediately;
- buyer is willing to commit to a higher price on unpaid shares so as
  to anticipate upcoming legislation that will make it harder to
  perform akin mergers/acquisitions.